# Trying to pass EMC Pre-Compliance Test without the use of electrolytic capacitor on DC/DC Converter

Tags: emc, emi-filtering

I’m designing a EMI filter for a DC/DC Converter Circuit and having trouble suppressing noise on 1.5-1.8MHz range. Usually an easy fix would be snap in a 100-220uF Electrolytic cap would do the trick but I don’t want to do it in here. Any suggestions?

Initial Scan:
[image]

Scan after filter is applied:
[image]

Here’s the filter structure so far:
[image]

Comment: Differential noise problem?

Comment: What does your layout look like?

Comment: Simulation shows the filter have nearly -200db reduction on that particular range. But real world says otherwise… outside interference are considered since the test is not in the lab but I don’t think there is one

Comment: @winny the layout is following manufacturer’s recommendations.

Comment: @winny maybe additional filter on the switching loop?

Comment: Are those capacitors you are currently using electrolytics or ceramics or something else? What is the voltage? What does the PCB design look like?

Comment: @Justme capacitors are all ceramic s, voltage is 12V, PCB design is following manufacturer’s recommendation to reduce EMI and improved thermal performance, but probably can do further improvements on the layout tho

Comment: Consider using copper pours on adjacent layers as "free" capacitance.

Comment: That unfortunately tells us very little. How many PCB layers? What goes on which layer?

Comment: @winny 2 layers, all traces are on TOP. BOT are ground only. Both layers are filled with ground plane copper pour.

Comment: Consider what a 4 layer board costs compared to all your filters.

Comment: I would guess 1/3 of that filter is sufficient. Also, your converter's compensation may be wildly off? Note you can always emulate an electrolytic by putting some resistance in series with a wad of ceramic capacitors.

Comment: Wouldn't a 220 uF electrolytic have a SRF well below 1.5 MHz?  Maybe @TimWilliams suggestion of some added series resistance with ceramics would perform better.

Comment: Layout is evident in the 20-50MHz range (notice the forest of spikes identifying it as SMPS harmonics). Below 20MHz, the filter works as expected; above, layout strays and component parasitics dominate, but the filter still does some work (~34MHz is -20dB). The peak in question is NOT on the filtered connection differential mode. Actually that peak didn't exist in the previous plot at all, or the peaks move around for unknown reasons.

Comment: The damping value of an electrolytic will only apply at extremely low frequencies (say for SMPS compensation?) and is not relevant to the plots here (well, perhaps the sidelobes of the first plot, which as I commented may indicate poor compensation). This is why we must see the full schematics, layout, and how the board is connected to related equipment or CDNs.

Comment: Have you tried to do an AC simulation of your filter with parasitics included?

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you elaborate on converter’s compensation?

Comment: @winny that being said…. CMC is the most expensive component in this filter, switch to 4 layer board would be slightly cheaper than the filter… by a few cents?

Comment: @TravisSu Specifically, the sidebands/lobes on the SMPS harmonics are suspicious, which could suggest a stray oscillation. It could also be intentional (a periodic load?), or *maybe* a control scheme. (I don't think it's burst mode, there aren't enough harmonics to the lobes; but perhaps that's another explanation too.)

Comment: @TravisSu If you make a million boards annually, you could pocket 10 000 USD. Have you tested for immunity yet? Simulated the filter?